# C++ recursion through inheritance tree with typeid causing this pointer problems

Tags: c++, recursion, this, typeid

I am trying to do something very similar to this.  I probably am misunderstanding some fundamental rule of programming but any help in understanding why this doesn't work would be appreciated.  I'd also like tips for how I could make something like this happen:

To be clear I would like a call to C.RecursiveMethod() to then call B.RecursiveMethod() which then calls A.RecursiveMethod() which then hits the base case and so unravels.  What actually ends up happening is C.RecursiveMethod() calls C.RecursiveMethod() which calls C.RecursiveMethod() on until doomsday.

Thanks ahead of time, and sorry if I suck, this is my first post.

```
class A 
{
    void RecursiveMethod()
    {
        if (typeid(*this) == typeid(A))
            // Base case
        else
            SUPER::RecursiveMethod()  // The problem lies here

        // Do stuff
    };
};

class B : A 
{
    typedef A SUPER;
};

class C : B
{
    typedef B SUPER;
};

A.RecursiveMethod();   // Works, base case only
C.RecursiveMethod();   // Infinite loop
                       // this pointer is always of type C

// Also tried in vain: 
//  this->SUPER::RecursiveMethod()
//  SUPER* superCast = dynamic_cast<SUPER*>(this); superCast->RecursiveMethod();
```

Comment: There is no `A... B... C... RecursiveMethod`. There is only one `RecursiveMethod` which is shared between them. And since `this` never changes (i.e. `typeid(*this)` is always the same) then you get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Overloads for the RecursiveMethod() for all of your classes. As freakish stated, your pointer: `if (typeid(*this) == typeid(A))` always points to the same class, hence the infinite loop

Comment: Thanks for your input.  The "beauty" of what I was trying to do here was to avoid this code being repeated in every class.  I was hoping there might be a way to do this.

Comment: I am not completely clear on exactly what you're trying to do here: " a call to C.RecursiveMethod() to then call B.RecursiveMethod() which then calls A.RecursiveMethod() which then hits the base case and so unravels."

Comment: @Chiralmaera were you able to solve this issue yet??

Comment: Everyone helped me understand what I was doing wrong.  It ended up the project I was working on changed form enough that I abandoned this recursive approach entirely.  Before that I had simply copied the RecursiveMethod into each derived class which worked ok, but is not ideal to me.  You lose the simplicity.  You might as well change the call to SUPER::RecursiveMethod() to be Base::RecursiveMethod and remove the typedefs..  I would love to know a clever way to make this work.